# dynamic component scanning in grails

Tags: java, spring, grails

I have a toy project on grails, where is the main idea is to load user components at runtime into  application.
By my idea, user writes his own beans (controllers and services) right in my web application as a DSL bean set and, presses the button, and beans from that file are load int the application context. At the moment I can load and wire these beans with AC, but grails does not treat them as controllers. I suppose there are two strategies to find controllers in the grails application: grails scans beans that are located in some "magic" folder, wires them and supposes that all the methods of this bean are requestmappings. The second way to find controllers is to annotate them with @Controller and @RequestMapping. And that is what I don't know how to do.
When I annotate these DSL beans with @Controller and wire them, they do appear at the controller list, claculated this way

```
package ealo;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfo;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping;

public class ControllerLister {

    @Autowired
    private RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping;

    //@PostConstruct
    public void init1() {
        Map<RequestMappingInfo, HandlerMethod> handlerMethods
                 = this.requestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandlerMethods();

        //System.out.println("111 "+handlerMethods);
        for (Entry<RequestMappingInfo, HandlerMethod> item : handlerMethods.entrySet()) {
            RequestMappingInfo mapping = item.getKey();
            HandlerMethod method = item.getValue();

            // System.out.println("111");
            for (String urlPattern : mapping.getPatternsCondition().getPatterns()) {
                System.out.println(
                         method.getBeanType().getName() + "#" + method.getMethod().getName()
                         + " <-- " + urlPattern);

                 if (urlPattern.equals("some specific url")) {
                     //add to list of matching METHODS
                 }
             }
         }
     }

 }
```

But it happens only when I change something in the project at runtime. I suppose grails rescans components at that moment. Anyway, even when I see these beans listed, I cannot make any request to them, getting 404. If a do not annotate the beans, I cannot even see them listed.

I need an idea how to solve this problem grails way or annotation way. Grails way is in preference. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wrote a plugin that lets you register controllers at runtime, and compose controllers from various sources. See [the plugin page](http://grails.org/plugin/dynamic-controller) for more info, and check out [the app-info plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/app-info) for an example of its use.

Comment: OK. I see that I can do everithing I need just using grailsApplication.addArtifact(). As I understand the documentation in guieses itself about the type of the artefact and even wires it. Now I've got another problem: 
     ERROR filter.UrlMappingsFilter  - Error when matching URL mapping [/(*)/(*)?/(*)?(.(*))?]:null
seems like it brakes all the mappings. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you're doing wrong is underthinking how much is involved :)  Look at what the plugin does.

Comment: Method `createDynamicController()` of class `DynamicControllerManager` in the plugin builds class definition as string, parses it with classloader of grails application, adds as artifact to grails application, initializes it, and regsters its class as bean definition. Is it enough to create a controller? :) A can see all other routines making mixin logic.